# How to construct and justify loop invariant, which allows to show partial correctness

Tags: algorithm, correctness, loop-invariant

I need to construct and justify a loop invariant with given specification:

```
{n > 0} P {q = | {j: a[j]=x and 0 <= j < n} |}
```

where *|A|* is a number of elements of set A. It means that *q* is equal to the number of elements from array *a* that are equal to *x*.

Code ***P*** is specified as:

```
{
int i = 0, q = 0;
while (i != n){
    if (a[i] == x)
        q = q + 1;
    i = i + 1;
}
```

I know that loop invariant must be true:

- before the loop starts
- before each iteration of the loop
- after the loop terminates

but I have no clue how should I find the right loop invariant, that would allow me to show partial correctness of P afterwards. I already tried to look at every single iteration of the loop and variables for random *n*, *x* and *a[0...n-1]* to see which values combined are constant while the loop is working, but it did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your code carefully. At the beginning, `q` is 0, and it only grows when you find new elements that are `== x`. So

`q = | {j: a[j]=x and 0 <= j < i} |`

is part of your invariant. Note that in your specification, you had `< n` instead of `< i`. Notice also that, at loop termination, `i == n`. So it will also be valid at the start. It will also be true at any point in between: so far, so good. Is anything else missing? Yes, we should also state that

`0 <= i <= n` -- because that describes the range of values of i (otherwise, `i` would be free to venture outside the array).

Is this all? Yes -- there is no other loop state left to describe. Therefore, your complete invariant looks like

`q = | {j: a[j]=x and 0 <= j < i} | and 0 <= i <= n`

When solving these exercises, you can try these 2 steps:

- try to describe in plain text what goes on in the algorithm: "I sweep `i` from 0 to n-1, stopping at n, and at every moment, I keep in `q` the amount of `x` that I have found within the array". All variables involved in the loop must be mentioned!.
- translate that plain text into math, while also making sure that your post-condition is reflected in the invariant, generally replacing the `n` by the loop counter (in this case, `i`)

As a thought experiment, try to write the invariant with the equivalent loop (but iterating from the end to the beginning) instead:

```
{
int i = n-1, q = 0;
while (i >= 0){
    if (a[i] == x)
        q = q + 1;
    i = i - 1;
}
```

Mouse over for answer (but try to figure it out first).

> `q = | {j: a[j]=x and i < j < n} | and -1 <= i < n`
>  Note the different limits, reflecting that `i` sweeps differently;
>  but the same overall structure